# app.set('x-powered-by', false) não funciona no expressjs

Tags: node.js, header, express.js

Olá, no meu código principal do meu app, com o uso do express, estou tentando remover o header "x-powered-by", e já usei tanto

```
app.disable("x-powered-by")
```

quanto

```
app.set("x-powered-by", false)
```

Além disse, já tentei usando o módulo helmet .

Mas, nenhum jeito surge efeito e o header continua a aparecer nas requisições.

Segue a estrutura do meu código:

```
const express        = require('express'),
      app            = express(),
      http           = require('http'),
      cors           = require('cors'),
      helmet         = require('helmet'),

app.set('x-powered-by', false);

...

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());

...

http
.createServer(app)
.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`running in port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Já testaste com o helmet usando `hidePoweredBy` e `setTo: 'outra coisa'`? Funciona bem para mim...

Comment: @Sergio, já, mas ainda continua mostrando o "Express".

Comment: Samir, dá uma olhada aqui: https://ide.c9.io/sergiocrisostomo/sopt-218873, consegues ver o header?

Comment: @Sergio, teria como você mandar em algum outro que não necessite desse signup?

Comment: Sim, esse dá para ver sem signup aqui: https://sopt-218873-sergiocrisostomo.c9users.io/ Clicando em "open app"

Comment: @Sergio, a resposta no header tem "x-powered-by: Renewable energies, love and good music"

Comment: Exato :) Podes mudar para uma string vazia.

Comment: O código que está a correr é https://jsfiddle.net/waqt6z3L/

Comment: @Sergio, da sua maneira, localmente não estava dando certo, mas ao subir pro host, funcionou. Podes colocar como resposta, caso queira. Obrigado! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso assim, com o helmet:

```
app.use(
    helmet({
        hidePoweredBy: {
            setTo: 'Renewable energies, love and good music'
        }
    })
);
```

E se quiseres podes passar uma string vazia no `setTo`.